# Give an example of a function that is integrable on the interval [0, 1] and incomplete on [0, 2].

Tags: definite-integrals

Give an example of a function that is integrable on the interval [0, 1] and not-integrable on [0, 2].

So , i was thinking about function ={-1, 0<=x<=1 and 0, 1<x<=2 , however i dont think that i

was going to accomplish anything by that and apart from Dirichlet function i cant think of

any good example of function that would be incomplete

Comment: What do you mean by "incomplete" ? Non continuous ?

Comment: And what do you mean by "integral"? These terms are not standard.

Comment: i meant that the function on the interval [0,1] can be integrable and non-integrable on [0, 2].

Comment: What about $$f : x \mapsto \left\lbrace \begin{array}[ll] \ \dfrac{1}{2-x} & \text{if }x \in [0,2) \\ 42 & \text{if }x=2 \end{array}\right. \quad ?$$